# Maintaining 1 sitemap.xml in two subdomains

Tags: seo, sitemap

Im trying to include an auto-generated `sitemap.xml` file whenever we build our frontend application.

Unfortunately due to legacy reasons, we use the same frontend build script on our production and staging servers.

As a result , this `sitemap.xml` with domain as `w.x.com` will also reside on our `w.staging.x.com` server

There will be only one correct `sitemap.xml` file with hostname `w.x.com` residing on our `w.x.com` server - but there will be a duplicate XML in staging

Is this ok or will it affect SEO/Crawlers etc

Comment: Is your staging environment available to crawlers? If not then as far as they are concerned that doesn't exist

Comment: Is your staging domain and main domain both verified in GSC with the same owner?

Comment: @DocRoot I'm sorry, are you referring to google search console? I don't recall doing any verification for my staging server. Basically both fall under the same domain right ? One is x.com and the other is staging.x.com

Comment: @Kannaj Yes, Google Search Console. Unless you've explicitly added a "domain property" (relatively new) and verified using the DNS verification method then `x.com` and `staging.x.com` are seen as two different properties and would need to be verified separately (if you wanted to).

Comment: i verified only for `x.com` but can also seem to add multiple properties like `a.staging.x.com` , `a.qa.x.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is not okay and it probably will affect your SEO.**

Staging should not be indexed.
This is because of duplicate content and crawling budget reasons.

You should only index your live version and show only live version pages within your sitemap.

Comment: I fail to see how having an "incorrect/invalid" sitemap of on a _staging_ site - for which you don't want indexed anyway - will have any effect on SEO of the main site (which would seem to be the concern here)? An "invalid" sitemap will simply be ignored. (The exception is if both sites are verified by the same owner in GSC - but the OP has not confirmed this. Either way, I don't see this as being "detrimental".) The concern is having the staging site crawlable in the first place (which again, the OP has not actually confirmed) - but that wasn't the question that was asked.